# OpenNi getData from Frame returns an empty array

Tags: qt, opencv, openni

I have a problem with depth video stream. I try to get a video frame from my depth video stream, but when I call `openni::VideoFrameRef::getData()`, I had an empty `imgBuf`

**Initialize Depth Stream**

```
status = depth.create(device, openni::SENSOR_DEPTH);
if(status == openni::STATUS_OK) {
    status = depth.start();
    if(status != openni::STATUS_OK) {
        (new QErrorMessage(this))->showMessage(openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError());
        depth.destroy();
    }
} else {
    (new QErrorMessage(this))->showMessage(openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError());
}

openni::VideoStream** m_streams = new openni::VideoStream*[2];
m_streams[0] = &depth;
m_streams[1] = &color;

openni::VideoFrameRef m_depthFrame;
openni::VideoFrameRef m_colorFrame;
```

**Set Video Frame and Getting Data**

```
int changedIndex;

openni::Status rc = openni::OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(m_streams, 1, &changedIndex, SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
if (rc != openni::STATUS_OK) {
    (new QErrorMessage(this))->showMessage(openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError());
    return;
}

status = depth.readFrame(&m_depthFrame);

if(openni::STATUS_OK == status && m_depthFrame.isValid()) {

    openni::VideoMode depthVideoMode = depth.getVideoMode();

    int depthWidth = depthVideoMode.getResolutionX();
    int depthHeight = depthVideoMode.getResolutionY();

    int buf_size = m_depthFrame.getDataSize();
    openni::SensorType s_type = m_depthFrame.getSensorType();

    openni::DepthPixel* pDepth = (openni::DepthPixel*)m_depthFrame.getData();
    const uint16_t* imgBuf = (const uint16_t*)m_depthFrame.getData();
    cv::Mat DethBuf;

    DethBuf.create(depthHeight, depthWidth, CV_16U);
    memcpy(DethBuf.data, imgBuf, depthHeight * depthWidth * sizeof(uint16_t));
    DethBuf.convertTo(DethBuf, CV_16U);
}
```

As a result, `imgBuf` is empty. I hope someone can help me find my mistake.

Comment: Perhaps checking out [gstreamer openni2 implementation](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/ext/openni2/gstopenni2src.cpp#n492) might help clarify while waiting for a longer reply.